# Parallel and non-parallel execution of tasks

Tags: java

I am creating a system which will perform few kinds of operation upon receiving commands from user. Some of the commands are:

- Acknowledgement (If user asks how are you, she returns back)
- Temperature (Returns current temperature)
- Photo capturing (Takes some pictures)
- Video capturing (Take a video)

The system has a camera so the last two tasks cannot be performed in parallel. But while capturing the images it can sense the temperature and return it back to the user.

I think to implement it I need to have some kind of parallel and non-parallel executions of tasks. I don't know if there is something in java concurrency exists which I can use to achieve this. I am not asking for any code. Any pointer on how it can be done will be very helpful for me.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java has special framework for executing commands. See the [java.util.concurrent.Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) hierarchy.

For example, `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` executes runnables based on internal thread pool. Max thread pool size of 1 means no paralell execution.

There are many examples for usage, like [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/threadpoolexecutor.html):

int  corePoolSize  =    5;
int  maxPoolSize   =   10;
long keepAliveTime = 5000;

```
ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                corePoolSize,
                maxPoolSize,
                keepAliveTime,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

Comment: Ok, so I will create two `ThreadPoolExecutor`s. One is for single processing tasks like image, video, which will maxPool=1 and another for parallel tasks like acknowledging or temperature etc with maxPool=2/3. I will submit this jobs to these two executors based on their category and they will `execute` those `Runnable`. Am I right?

Comment: Sound good. It's quite often to have many executors for many different applications in the same application.